# how continue a path from one point by using pen tools in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I use pen tool to draw around of shapes in my sketch in illustrator  ,  during drawing I do wrong  and the path is closed , I want to  continue  from one point of this path but I don't know how do it by pen

here is a picture of my probelm
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is still open, follow OghmaOsiris' answer.

If the file was closed and/or undo is not available, use the **Direct Selection Tool ** (White arrow) to click the section of path you do not want, and then tap the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.  Only that section should be removed. You can then use the pen tool to click one of the end anchors and continue drawing the path.

Answer (score 3):

Undo the last click (Ctrl+Z for Windows, Command+z for Mac) and with the Pen tool selected, hover over the last node you created and it should change to a '/'. When you click the node you'll be adding on to the path you created.

I also suggest changing your fill color to transparent until you've completed the path so you can see your sketch underneath completely.

Answer (score 2):

The above works, but if you don't want to delete and endpoint to continue drawing your path try this:

For a previously left open path:
Using the Selection Tool shortcut - "v"
Click to select object/path
Double click to open path in isolation mode
Pen tool "p"
Click on endpoint with pen tool - will have "/" icon hopefully.

Comment: I think your answer is probably exactly right...but it feels like you got cut off at the end.  If you do see the "/" icon, then can you just go ahead and start drawing?