# How to continue an unfinished curved path in InkScape

Tags: vector, inkscape, path, pen-tool, bezier-curve

I think I have found the Adobe Illustrator version of this question, at: **[how continue a path from one point by using pen tools in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26850/how-continue-a-path-from-one-point-by-using-pen-tools-in-illustrator)**

<sub>**[Another site:](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=9160)** suggests subpaths, but this doesn't seem to work because you have to stop, and go back, and smooth out that shared node.</sub>

But in Inkscape, can you "pick up" from where you left off with the Bezier / Pen Tool, to continue drawing a curved path?  (So that the continued path ***shares the same cusp / smooth / symmetric nodes***)?

I imagine this issue doesn't really matter with line / corner nodes.

**A Very Over-Simplified Use Case:**

- Guru Artist is making a vertically snaking "S" path, (to make a snake!).
- To begin, `Click+Drag`, then release to create a collinear segment.
- `Click+Drag` to create another.
- And again, and again ...
- ***Accidentally hit `Right+Click`*** - because of IRL Aggro from swooping dragon flying over house.
- Come back to computer, and want to continue creating this curve, for many more steps.

I am basically looking for the capability to "pick-up" the last node, or even delete the last segment, and continue on, maintaining all of the handles.

Is there a way to do this in InkScape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was writing and editing the question, I figured I would post my work-around/hack to help illustrate the issue.  I started trying to figure out what subpaths are, (per a similar question posted on another forum), that allows you to continue on and even modify the node time to symmetric, cusped, etc.

1. **`Double+Click`** your curved path to be able to see the path and nodes.
2. Select the Bezier Pen Tool, (or press `"B"`).
3. **`Click+Drag`** or just **`Click`** on the node you want to continue from.
4. **`Shift+U`** to start working in Cusp mode.

Although the node does end up being a cusp node, I still have no idea how to get it to turn into linear mode, smooth, symmetric, or corner - or even just delete that last node, to continue on.

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can skip number 1, if the path is already selected. Double-click will only work when you have the Selector tool active.

To change a node's type, use the shortcuts described in the keyboard shortcut list: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#idm2176